# Google Drive Full Text Search implementation

Tags: google-drive-api

I can use google cloud storage
Download and upload static file for example pdf.
Now I want use full text search with google drive api for c# code

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What have you tried?

Comment: I dont know google drive full text search c# code?

Answer (score 0):

everything you need is on this page

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list